# AngularJS ocLazyLoad and Json

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a problem with my code... i'm trying to do a table by json from a API.
But the table does not work, if you put static values on html, it works. But by json no.

```
.state('nimbus.produtos', {
        url: "/Produto",
        templateUrl: "/ProdutoContext/Produto/Index",
        controller: function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('//localhost:61115/api/produtoapi')
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.Produtos = data;
                    console.log("carregou API");
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    console.log("Erro ao acessar URL de produtos");
                });

        },
        resolve: {
            loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                    console.log("OCLazy carregou"),
                    {
                        serie: true,
                        files: ['/Scripts/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.js', '/Content/css/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.css']
                    },
                    {
                        serie: true,
                        name: 'datatables',
                        files: ['/Scripts/plugins/dataTables/angular-datatables.min.js']
                    },
                    {
                        serie: true,
                        name: 'datatables.buttons',
                        files: ['/Scripts/plugins/dataTables/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js']
                    },
                ]);
            }
        }

    })
```

I think the datatable has to load after JSON File, but it loads before JSON file.
how can i solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check the format of  `data` in  `$scope.Produtos = data;`  is it array with key values mappings or not. and before loading data table put $timeout while `data` get binded to view.

Comment: My json file has arrays, i can get all elements. but the buttons does not work because he loads after the table. I cannot go to page number 2, 3... Use the Search input... Because datatable doesn't understand that my json code are pure static html code